# In Yosemite, the 'Alerts" Alert style notification dismisses on its own

Tags: macos, notifications, alert

I've setup the Thyme app's notifications to be "Alerts" style, which requires the user to interact with it to dismiss it:

[image]

However, they dismiss on their own after about 5 minutes. How to configure these so they never dismiss on their own?

Comment: I think it is not possible that these notifications stay on your screen for ever. On the demo mac's in an apple store or Apple premium reseller they also pop up after the screen saver is disabled and they do not go away before the screen saver starts working again in approximately 5 minutes

Comment: The developer of the app has probably put some code in to make them disappear so that they don't keep piling up in Notification Center. You'll probably find that 'Banners' (which appear briefly on screen but remain visible in the Notification Center) will also magically disappear after 5 minutes.